# Autocomplete with any character in TextBox C#

Tags: c#, linq, autocomplete

I want to set the autocomplete to the textbox using LINQ to entities.

This is my code:

```
using (Reference_TraductionEntities context = new Reference_TraductionEntities())
{
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    var name = from a in context.Feuil1Prenom
               where a.PRENOMF.StartsWith("i")
               select a.PRENOMF;
    source.AddRange(name.ToArray());

    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

This code is OK , but just with the character "i",
I want autocomplete with any character entry in textbox

How can I fix it ?

Thanks,

Comment: then replace starts with "i" to starts with textbox1.text ?

Comment: What happens if You just remove the where?

Comment: if i remove Where, I get ERROR: vshost32.exe stopped working!!

Comment: Very Thanks BugFinder !!!

I solve it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Thanks BugFinder !!!!

I replace starts with "i" to starts with textbox1.text ...

```
using (Reference_TraductionEntities context = new Reference_TraductionEntities())
{
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    var name = from a in context.Feuil1Prenom
               where a.PRENOMF.StartsWith(textBox1.Text )
               select a.PRENOMF;
    source.AddRange(name.ToArray());

    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

It works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one

```
this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
if (t != null)
{
    //say you want to do a search when user types 3 or more chars
    if (t.Text.Length >= 3)
    {
        //SuggestStrings will have the logic to return array of strings either from cache/db
        string[] arr = SuggestStrings(t.Text);

        AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        collection.AddRange(arr);

        this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
     }
  }
}
```